# Azure Frontdoor: Requests go to invididual backends, why?

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-front-door

I have set up an Azure Frontdoor Load Balancer with 2 backends, hosting an Angular app. When looking at the network traffic in the browser's developer tools, I see that only the first few requests for *.html and *.js files go to the loadbalancer. Beginning with the `GET options` request, all subsequent requests seem to go directly to the backend #2 (in red in the picture below):
[image]

This means, if the backend #2 goes down, the client gets 404 errors, and won't be automatically redirected to backend #1, unless the user reloads the browser window with F5.

I'm not sure how the Angular app gets the actual backend host's URL. I cannot see any header or cookie which would provide this information. The headers of the first request for login.html look like this - no sign of the backend URL anywhere:
[image]

My questions are

1. how does the client get the backend host's URL?
2. is there a way to define that ALL requests go through the loadbalancer?
3. Would that even be a good idea? Or is this the "intended behaviour", meaning that the user WILL see 404 errors and have to reload the page manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the application that is doing it, not the azure front door. The app must be constructing the url based on where it is hosted and them making a request. The front door will set the host header same as the app service's hostname. In that case, the application would see it's request to come as if the user typed that in the browser. You would typically want to use custom hostname e.g. neonapp-dev.yourcompanyname.com. When you do that both app services and the front door would have the custom host configured. While configuring the front door, you would use this as a host header rather than the default which is app services host name. Then everything would work fine as the app would never see the app services name as host header.

More details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-backend-pool#backend-host-header